# Developing in docker-compose. Getting the container to recognise code changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a docker-container with a Python3 environment and various libraries installed.

I'm trying to develop a simple Python program against this environment.

So what I have is a volume with my source code outside the container which is ADDed and set as WORKDIR in the Dockerfile.

I'm then shelling into the container and trying to run the program on the command-line.

When I hit an error, I want to simply change the source in my editor which is outside the container, and run again.

However, when I do this, the executing code in the container doesn't seem to be taking any notice of the changes I made.

If I do

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and rebuild the container then it does.

Obviously this is very slow.

Surely it should be possible for the container to see changes to the code I'm working on without being rebuilt? If so, how do I make this happen?

Comment: please take a look at mounts

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes for your case you wnat to use type:bind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ADD` bakes files into a container image, so as you've noticed, updating files in a running application requires an entire container rebuild and restart. To get around this, you can mount a directory on your host machine over the path you've copied into your container using `ADD`.

To do this with Docker, you can use `-v` or `--volume`. Using Docker Compose, you can list the directory to be mounted under `volumes:`. For example, if you had the following in your build file:

```
# Copy app code into the container working directory
ADD /my/app/code /usr/app/src
```

You can then mount your *live* code over the baked-in files at container start time (note that directory paths must be absolute - you can use `$PWD` for this):

```
$ docker run -v /my/live/app/code:/usr/app/src python:latest
$ docker run -v "$PWD"/app/code:/usr/app/src python:latest
```

The `docker-compose.yml` equivalent is as follows:

```
my-service:
  image: python:latest
  volumes:
    - /my/live/app/code:/usr/app/src
    - ./relative/paths:/work/too
```

There's more about bind mounts in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).